# Getting Error when import my android project "The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher"

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

When opening previous project getting Error "Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher."

[Project Build Grade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syeta.png)

Comment: You should never post image of code. Remember that.

Comment: remove `-alpha09` and update kotlin_version to 1.3.72

Comment: @IR42 can you tell after removing -alpha09 how can i update kotlin_version to 1.3.72?